# Debug assertion in WTL splitter sample

Tags: c++, wtl

When read or clear clipboard is clicked from the mainframe menu in the [WTL sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4518/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-VII-Splitter-Windows) compiled with vs2013

CHAIN_COMMANDS_MEMBER(m_wndFormatList) pases messages from the mainframe to the member list control but the message is null?

**Stack trace:**

```
WTLClipSpy.exe!ATL::CWindowImplRoot<WTL::CListViewCtrlT<ATL::CWindow> ::SetMsgHandled(int bHandled) Line 3213   C++
WTLClipSpy.exe!CClipSpyListCtrl::ProcessWindowMessage(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam, long & lResult, unsigned long dwMsgMapID) Line 30 C++
WTLClipSpy.exe!CMainFrame::ProcessWindowMessage(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam, long & lResult, unsigned long dwMsgMapID) Line 41   C++
```

**Debug output:**

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...nloads\source\WTL4MFC7_demo\WTLClipSpy.\Debug\WTLClipSpy.exe
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlwin.h
Line: 3213

Expression: pMsg != 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely to be a regression problem with a not so popular `CHAIN_COMMANDS_MEMBER` macro.

A workaround might look like this:

```
    //CHAIN_COMMANDS_MEMBER(m_wndFormatList)
    if(uMsg == WM_COMMAND)
    {
        lResult = m_wndFormatList.SendMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        if(lResult == 0)
            return TRUE;
    }
```

Or, if you prefer to bypass `SendMessage` API (makes sense), then you will need to take care of `m_pCurrentMsg` initialization in the chained control. A better but longer fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "take care of m_pCurrentMsg initialization in the chained control"?

Comment: WTL window procedures (`WindowProc`, `DialogProc` implementations) initialize respective message map handlers' `m_pCurrentMsg` before executing actual map handlers, then clear the variable appropriately. `CHAIN_COMMANDS_MEMBER` does not do it and executes the handlers directly. This results in problem you reported. It takes to update macro code to add missing variable initialization, or the way I suggested above is also more or less fine.

Comment: #define CHAIN_COMMANDS_MEMBER(theChainMember) \ theChainMember.m_pCurrentMsg = m_pCurrentMsg; \ if(uMsg == WM_COMMAND) \ CHAIN_MSG_MAP_MEMBER(theChainMember) in atlwinx.h seems to work.